# How to make list contents appear side by side in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to show the contents of two lists, side by side in one textbox.

The problem is that the second one just appears underneath the first one.

Below, the contents in red should be under the maxlen column, NOT under the number 50 in the Seq column.

[image]

```
  private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {


                  textBox1.Text = "Seq         MaxLen\r\n";
                  foreach (object o in MaxLen)
                  {
                      textBox1.Text += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, MaxLen);
                  }
                  foreach (object a in SeqIrregularities)
                  {
                      textBox1.Text += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, SeqIrregularities);
                  }
          }
```

Comment: You will need to pad the text to get it to show up correctly.

Comment: You could add either some non breaking space, or a tab.

Comment: Why wouldn't you consider a control with columns?

Comment: @DROPtableusers I thought of that, but how would that work with my code? I'm new so I dont know much syntax at all

Comment: @IAbstract and Brian please elabroate

Comment: @user7068 you can see an example of padding in my answer below.  It will add characters to your string to make the whole string a constant length.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable in all WPF controls but there are two that come to mind: ListView and GridControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I answered too fast and completely wrong the first time!

You need to loop through both lists and see if you have values and the apply padding (as Brian suggested) to format the text

```
        textBox1.Text = "Seq".PadRight(10) +  "MaxLen";

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(MaxLen.Count, SeqIrregularities.Count); i++)
        {
            textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            string text = String.Empty;
            if (i < MaxLen.Count)
            {
                text = MaxLen[i].ToString();
            }
            text = text.PadRight(10);
            if (i < SeqIrregularities.Count)
            {
                text += SeqIrregularities[i];
            }
            textBox1.Text += text;
        }
```

Edit: typo in the second "if" should be SeqIrregularities instead of MaxLen

Comment: Just trying to understand the logic behind this, if maxlen list has greater contents then you are filling the text variable with all contents of the maxlen list. HOWEVER, wont this completely exclude adding the second list contents to the variable text? (This is because the second if statement will be false if the first list is greater in contents). Which it should be, but then HOW would I display values from the second list to the textbox?

Comment: forgot to tag the last time.

Comment: Anything is there?  @kim

Comment: This is to loop through both lists, but if they aren't the same size use the count of the longer list (Math.Max).
There was a mistake in outputting the SeqIrregularities in the second if.

Comment: Okay, I finally wrote real code in VS and it works.  Make sure to use a font where each character has equal spacing for the Padding to work (I used Consolas)

Comment: Hey Kim do you think it will be easier to use a datagrid view ? Your answer is very helpful :) I'm just wondering if I should use a datagrid

Comment: Yup.  Datagrid might be better.  But then the approach is totally different.  Load a DataTable with rows that contain your data and then bind it to the grid.

Comment: this is what I mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982435/how-to-populate-datagrid-with-list-values-as-separate-columns-in-c-sharp/19982626?noredirect=1#19982626

Answer (score 1):

So right now, your `TextBox` is removing the extra whitespace. You need to set `xml:space="preserve"` on your `TextBox`.

Really though, I would use two `TextBoxes` or an `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that those list are of the same length (if not it will bit more complicated):

```
string result = "Seq         MaxLen\r\n";
for (int i = 0; i < MaxLen.Count; i++) {
    result += String.Format("{0}       {1}\r\n", SeqIrregularities[i].ToString(), MaxLen[i].ToString());
}
textBox1.Text = result;
```

Comment: They are not the same length :(

Comment: @user7068 so just find out which one is the shorter one and apply the above method. Then if `SeqIrregularities` is longer go with rest of its elements with: `result += String.Format("{0}\r\n", SeqIrregularities[i].ToString());` otherwise finish off MaxLen with: `result += String.Format("_________{1}\r\n", MaxLen[i].ToString());` (where _ is ' ')

Comment: Hey @artur gzesiak 
can you pls write that response as an edit to your original post. The code is  difficult for me to read in the comments section. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

```
       textBox1.Text = "Seq".PadRight(10) +"\tMaxLen\r\n";
       for(int i = 0; i < SeqIrregularities.Count() || i < MaxLen.Count(); i++)
       {
           string temp = "";
           if(i >= SeqIrregularities.Count())
               temp = "".PadRight(10) + "\t" + list2[i];
           else
               if(i >= MaxLen.Count())
                   temp = SeqIrregularities[i].PadRight(10);
               else
                   temp = SeqIrregularities[i].PadRight(10) + "\t" + MaxLen[i];
           textBox1.Text += temp + "\r\n";
       }
```

With this, each entry should be adjusted even if other entries are empty.