# How to populate datagrid with list values as separate columns in c#

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I already have an SQlite database setup. Right now I'm parsing through it. For example, if certain values in the column Seq are >30 I transfer those values to a list. *I want to use that list, to populate a datagrid view so the user can see what values were > 30*

**How do I populate a data grid view with multiple lists? Basically column 1 should be list1, column 2, list 2, etc.**

EDIT: DOES anyone think I should use a list view instead? If so, how?

Here's my code for parsing to obtain values for my lists. Now I need to somehow populate a DGV with these lists.

```
  string sql4 = "select * from abc";
       SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql4, sqlite_conn);

       // The datareader allows us to read the table abc row by row
       SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

       // What happens next: We are trying to parse each column for irregularities to show to the user. For example if a value in column
       // Seq is >30, we need to let the user know. We do this by adding all values >30 to the SeqIrregularities list. 

       while (reader.Read())
       {
           int seq;
           if (int.TryParse(reader["Seq"].ToString(), out seq))
               if (seq > 30)
               {

                   SeqIrregularities.Add(seq);
                   seq1 = true;
               }
           int maxlen;
           if (int.TryParse(reader["MaxLen"].ToString(), out maxlen))
               if (maxlen> 30.00)
               {

                   MaxLen.Add(maxlen);
                   maxlen1 = true;
               }



       }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd create an adapter class to take your multiple lists and populate either a custom object or perhaps a datatable.  Then you can bind that object as the datasource to your grid.

```
public DataTable ConvertListsToDatatable(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    DataColumn column;
    DataRow row;

    // add the first column
    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    column.ColumnName = "List1Id";
    dt.Columns.Add(column);

    // add the second column
    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    column.ColumnName = "List2Id";
    dt.Columns.Add(column);

    int i = 0;
    while ((list1 != null)&&(i < list1.Count) || (list2 != null)&&(i < list2.Count))
    {
        row = dt.NewRow();

        if (list1 != null)
        {
            if (i < list1.Count)
            {
                row["List1Id"] = List1[i];
            }
        }

        if (list2 != null)
        {
            if (i < list2.Count)
            {
                row["List2Id"] = List2[i];
            }
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        i++;
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: how would I actually do that

Comment: Don't have visual studio on this laptop but something like this is the quick and dirty way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother making lists in the first place.  Just load a table directly.

```
  DataTable myData = new DataTable();
  DataColumn seqCol = new DataColumn("Seq", typeof (int));
  DataColumn maxLenCol = new DataColumn("MaxLen", typeof (int));
  myData.Columns.Add(seqCol);
  myData.Columns.Add(maxLenCol);

  while (reader.Read())
  {
    var row = myData.NewRow();
    bool addRow = false;
    int seq;
    if (int.TryParse(reader["Seq"].ToString(), out seq))
      if (seq > 30)
      {
        row[seqCol] = seq;
        addRow = true;
      }
    int maxlen;
    if (int.TryParse(reader["MaxLen"].ToString(), out maxlen))
      if (maxlen > 30.00)
      {
        row[maxLenCol] = maxlen;
        addRow = true;
      }
    if (addRow)
    {
      myData.Rows.Add(row);
    }
  }
```

Then bind this table to a grid

```
 DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
  dgv.DataSource = myData;
```